# How to subscript a Postgres column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres query:

```
SELECT main
FROM (
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN (col_a, col_b)
  END as main
FROM "table1"
LIMIT 100) inner_t
```

Which returns a single column of values in the format `(value_a, value_b)` in each row. I want the outer query to format those values so that all the `value_a`'s and `value_b`'s are in their own separate columns.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Output screenshot:

[image]

http://example.com/path-to-ghosts.jpg

Comment: Are you sure that query runs? Or is just a pseudo code of what you want?

Comment: It runs, I just renamed it to avoid using work specific column names

Comment: That shouldnt . `CASE` cant return a touple

Comment: I've added a screenshot of my output... It's definitely spitting something out

Comment: Try it yourself.. It should work

Comment: Is this not just a simple split?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: it returns a single column which is an anonymous record type.

Comment: The cleanest solution is to write two CASE expressions and return two separate columns.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Is there anyway to do this in one case expression @a_horse_with_no_name? I have like 50+ columns that I need to add into this case statement so it wouldn't be feasible to write 50 case statements

Comment: I might have answers. But I won't spend more time on a question that won't disclose the Postgres version in use.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter version 9.4

Comment: Postgres 9.4 reaches EOL Feb 2020. Consider upgrading to a current version. https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Answer (score 1):

You can abuse row_to_json to do this, but it is probably best to avoid anonymous record types in the first place.

```
SELECT row_to_json(main)->>'f1', row_to_json(main)->>'f2'
FROM (
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN (col_a, col_b)
  END as main
FROM "table1"
LIMIT 100) inner_t
```

To give a concrete example (after running `pgbench -i`):

```
SELECT row_to_json(main)->>'f1', row_to_json(main)->>'f2'
FROM (
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN (aid, bid)
  END as main
FROM pgbench_accounts
LIMIT 100) inner_t;
```

But it only works in v10 and up.

Comment: This yields: `ERROR: record type has not been registered`

Comment: Works for me.  What version are you using?

Comment: Postgres version 9.4

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an explanation than an actual answer. But it won't fit into a comment.

The thing is, SQL is a strictly typed language. Postgres demands to know the number and data types in the `SELECT` list at call time. The `*`-expansion in `SELECT * FROM ..` is based on registered types. Postgres *knows* the columns of a table because the structure is saved in the catalog tables.

The expression nested in your construct `(col_a, col_b)` is short for `ROW(col_a, col_b)` and a ROW constructor creates an **anonymous record**. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS)

> By default, the value created by a `ROW` expression is of an anonymous
>   record type. If necessary, it can be cast to a named composite type —
>   either the row type of a table, or a composite type created with
>   `CREATE TYPE AS`.

Postgres does not know how to expand an anonymous record. `*`-expansion does not work.

You could cast like the manual says. But that's only an option if the type is stable, i.e. you always put in the same number of columns with the same data types. And that still would not preserve column *names*.

So, for the best solution, first define:

- Obviously you want to preserve column **vales**.
- Do you also want to preserve column **names**?
- Do you also want to preserve column **types**?

And:

- Is the number of columns in the expression always the same?
- Are data types always the same?
- The `CASE` condition is stable or based on other columns?

If the true aim of the game is to fit multiple values in a single CASE expression, you only care about ***values***, create a text array instead:

```
SELECT main[1] AS col_a, main[2] AS col_b
FROM  (
   SELECT CASE WHEN true THEN ARRAY[col_a::text, col_b::text] END AS main
   FROM   table1
   LIMIT  100
   ) inner_t;
```

You lose **name** and **type**. You can cast and add aliases if you *know* name & type.

Else you have to describe your use case more closely - in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Try Below query

```
SELECT split_part(main,',',1) as Val1,split_part(main,',',2) as Val2
FROM (
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN (col_a, col_b)
  END as main
FROM "table1"
LIMIT 100) inner_t
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Can't use `split_part` on an anonymous data type